# do cohomologically Kähler classes extend to Kähler classes?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $f: X \to S$ be a proper morphism from a complex manifold to a small disc which is smooth away from $Y = f^{-1}(0)$, an snc divisor. A class $\omega \in H^2(Y)$ is called cohomologically Kähler if restricts to a Kähler class on every irreducible component of $Y$. The fact that $X$ retracts onto $Y$ (Clemens) implies that there is a map $H^2(Y) \to H^2(X_t)$ for any $t \neq 0$ sufficiently close to 0 (pull back under retraction then restrict to $X_t$).

My question is: if $\omega \in H^2(Y)$ is cohomologically Kähler, is its image in $H^2(X_t)$ Kähler?

Proposition 1.41 of Kollár-Mori confirms a similar fact in projective situation: if $D$ is a divisor on $X$ such that $D \cap Y$ is ample, then $D \cap X_t$ is ample for $t$ in sufficiently small neighbourhood of 0.